# sacar datos de array en javascript

Tags: ajax

Tnego una funcion en ajax donde obtengo datos en el success

```js
function editarUsuario(id_usu) {
    alert(id_usu);

        $.ajax({  
            url: "EditServlet",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                id:id_usu
            },
            success: function (info_usu) {
                alert(info_usu);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("no trae datos");
            }
        });
}
```

pongo un alert para mostrar a info_usu

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como obtengo unicamente el nombre?
espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Cuando quieres saber la información exacta de un dato la mejor manera es usar `console.log()` en este caso puedes ver si es un array y visualizar cada uno de sus nodos o si simplemente te trae otro dato que tienes que tratar de manera diferente saludos espero te ayude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero deberias saber que tipo de dato tienes en info_usu, parece que es un array, pero para asegurarte puedes hacerlo poniendo en el alert typeof(info_usu).

Si es un array, solo tienes que poner en el alert el indice que te interese.

`alert(info_usu[1])`

Si fuese un string, ya que los datos están separados por ',' podrías convertirlo en un array:

`let datos = info_usu.split(',')
 alert(datos[1])`

y luego referirte al elemento del array como te he dicho mas arriba.

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ya quedo